# ffmpeg continue listen port

Tags: streaming, ffmpeg, rtmp

I'm trying to configure restream server, ffmpeg listen on rtmp://ip:port and output to few stream services(youtube, twitch...etc) the problem is when I stop OBS streaming(using this on local pc) ffmpeg on server going down and i need manually run it next time I go stream. Can't find option in ffmpeg dock which will make ffmpeg continue listening even if input source go down. Maybe I'm missing something in docs or it's time to make scripts which will restart ffmpeg?

I'm using this command for ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -re -listen 1 -i rtmp://i.p:1234 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -maxrate 3500k -bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://live-ams.twitch.tv/app/key
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you work with Linux, you could make a systemd services:

```
[Unit]
Description=ffmpeg listening and forward stream
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
PIDFile=/tmp/ffstreamer.pid
ExecStart= /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -re -listen 1 -i rtmp://i.p:1234 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -maxrate 3500k -bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://live-ams.twitch.tv/app/key

ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID
Restart=always
User=www-data

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When the input fails, it starts the process again.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use udp instead of tcp
being connectionless it doesn't end the process